# getting the domain name of DHCP on Android

Tags: android, macos, networking, dns, fedora-25

I would like to get the value of `domain`/`search` that can be found in `/etc/resolv.conf` of MacOS and Linux on Android.

Here are examples on MacOS and Linux (Fedora 25):

MacOS:

```
#
# Mac OS X Notice
#
# This file is not used by the host name and address resolution
# or the DNS query routing mechanisms used by most processes on
# this Mac OS X system.
#
# This file is automatically generated.
#
domain home
nameserver 195.121.1.34
nameserver 195.121.1.66
```

Linux:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search home
nameserver 195.121.1.34
nameserver 195.121.1.66
```

As you can see, the value that I am looking for in above cases is `home`. Any idea how I can get it on Android?

## What I am trying to do?

I am trying to make an Android app that depending on the setup of network, would behave differently. For example, it tries to lookup a service `foo.home` (note that `home` is dynamic and depends on network) and if it succeeded, it is gonna use that server. Otherwise, it will query a public service to find out the server that it should use.

Comment: Please show some of your code, and state the problem or exception you have encountered.

Comment: @jww I don't have any code for the android side at the moment. All I know is to where I can find what I want on MacOS and Linux. However, `resolv.conf` does not exist on Android. So I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The point of the search path is that it is *automatically* applied to queries so your application does not need to explicitly add it to the domain.

I'm not sure what language you are trying to use since you're targeting different platforms here, but just as an example:

```
// start with the unqualified name
service = "foo";
try {
    InetAddress.getByName(addr);
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    // if `foo' did not resolve, use the external service
    // specified by the fully qualified name
    service = "public.whatever.com"
}
```

Comment: Here is the problem with what you suggest:

Imagine that I have two instances of this setup. One for `work`, and one for `home`. When I connect to my network at home, the `resolv.conf` file gets populated with `domain behrooz-home` and when I connect at work, the value is `domain behrooz-work`.

Therefore, what I will be passing to `InetAddress.getByName` is gonna be different depending on network. It can not be static.

Comment: Just pass the **bare** hostname.  The point is that you don't need to specify the local domain name, it is applied automatically if you pass a hostname without a domain name specified.

Comment: So, the service is `foo.behrooz-work` or `foo.behrooz-home` depending on the network that I am using. What do you mean by *bare* hostname? The only part that I know is `foo` but foo is not gonna resolve anything. `foo.behrooz-home` will work and not `foo` or `behrooz-home`! That is why somehow I want to figure out the value of second part and add `foo` to it.

Comment: What do you mean `foo` is not going to resolve? You've tried that? What happens if you're at home and you do `ping foo`? Is it different from doing `ping foo.behrooz-work`?

Comment: Unfortunately no, because we do not necessarily configure the networks that user is gonna use.